# Invalid or Corrupt lib file opencv_core220d.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

I'm struggling with trying to get OpenCV 2.2 libraries to work with my project (running VSC++, 2010).  I followed the instructions at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B.  When I run my code (sample code from above link) I get the following message...

```
...\OpenCV-BUILD-2.2\lib\Debug\opencv_core220d.lib : 
fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x85DA
```

I've tried to rebuild my OpenCV libraries using CMake, but it still shows that lib file as being invalid or corrupt.  Does anybody have an idea as to what could be the issue or suggestions on how to troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on the OpenCV Wiki FAQ

> Make sure "c:\Program Files\OpenCV\bin" (or the equivalent for your installation) is included in your PATH variable.

Once I added the bin folder to my path, everything worked fine.